# Sharepoint 2019: How to close sharepoint screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint

I am developing a REACT custom screen (see the image below on the right side) in Sharepoint. The part that I wrote starts with the heading **New company**. The only part that is part of the system is the X button in the top right corner. The X button is not part of the file that I wrote. I have no control over it and I also think that I do not have access to it. This X button is used to close the screen.

[image]

Part of my custom screen is the CLOSE button that is placed at the bottom. I want to use this button to close the screen, therefore, I need to associate this button with a method (function) that will close the screen. But I have no idea what kind of method to use.

In other words, the functionality of the X button (in the top right corner) and my CLOSE button should be the same. Both of these buttons should close the screen.

Perhaps I could use the X button to search for the method that closes the screen. I tried that but with no success.

I also tried to use the window.close() method, but had no success too.

I will be grateful for any tips, help, or directions.